# How do I access workspaces by number on macOS Sierra?

Tags: keyboard, trackpad, shortcut

I'm running macOS Sierra 0.12.3 (16D32).

By exploding the desktop (four finger swipe up on trackpad) and then moving the mouse to the top bar I can create/update/destroy my workspaces.

With a four-finger swipe left/right or `C-left/right` I can move to the left and right.Also with a tool like [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/) I'm able to set shortcuts to move left/right.

I'd like to create a shortcut to access the workspaces by number. For example given the following workspaces Desktop 1-4:

[image]

I'd like to find a tool or system event where I could jump right to Desktop 3 perhaps with a keybinding like `Cmd + 3`.

- Does such a tool, or system event exist on macOS where I can access my workspaces by number instead of only moving left or right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access different spaces in Sierra with `control + number` keys. But first, you must enable it in the Keyboard shortcut settings:

1. Go to Keyboard Settings (`System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts`)
2. Select `Mission Control` from the left column of choices.
3. Check these boxes: `Switch to Desktop 1`, `Switch to Desktop 1`

You can now use switch between spaces using short keys.

Comment: There's only "Switch to Desktop 1", but no "Switch to Desktop 2" (or further).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works well but keep in mind - if two displays are connected to a Mac, the space number order may not be what you expect.

Focus on which desktop is active and if you let spaces rearrange themselves in settings.

I've made this mistake ... it does switch to desktop of my second monitor , as long as this desktop number X is associated with this second monitor ...
So if for ex, I do have:
monitor 1 -> desktop 1 and 2 and 3
monitor 2 --> desktop 4 and 5

then , Switch to Desktop 5 will make my monitor 2 to switch from desktop 4 to 5 ...

But I wanted to have an independent desktop counting for every monitor. It is more intuitive.
So I wanted to have
monitor 1 : desktop 1 , 2 and 3
monitor 2 : desktop 1 , 2

but this is not the way it works currently ... I will try to find for a solution / workaround with BetterTouch application that I have